# Airflow SYNTAX error : leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers

Tags: airflow

Hello I was trying to run a xcom clear dag on every sunday . But the Airflow dag thrown me the error as below . airflow version 2.4.3 . For scheduling i am using the cron expression

```
Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/xcom_clear_30_days.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 947, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/xcom_clear_30_days.py", line 10
    with DAG(dag_id="cleanup_30_days_older_xcom_values", schedule_interval="5 16 * * 0", start_date=datetime(2023,12,03, 16 ,05),tags=["cleanup_30_days"]) as dag:
                                                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers
```

code

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session
from airflow.models import XCom
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from sqlalchemy import func

with DAG(dag_id="cleanup_30_days_older_xcom_values", schedule_interval="5 16 * * 0", start_date=datetime(2023,12,03, 16 ,05),tags=["cleanup_30_days"]) as dag:
    # cleanup_xcom
    @provide_session
    def cleanup_xcom(session=None, **context):
        dag = context["dag"]
        dag_id = dag._dag_id
        # It will delete all xcom of the dag_id
        ts_limit = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(days=30)
        print(f"printing the time until the xcom cleared {ts_limit}")
        print(f"printing session {session}")
        ##session.query(XCom).filter(XCom.execution_date <= ts_limit).delete()
        session.query(XCom).filter(XCom.execution_date <= ts_limit).delete(synchronize_session='fetch')


    clean_xcom = PythonOperator(
        task_id="clean_xcom",
        python_callable=cleanup_xcom,
        provide_context=True
        # dag=dag
    )

    start = DummyOperator(task_id="start")
    end = DummyOperator(task_id="end", trigger_rule="none_failed")

    start >> clean_xcom >> end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `start_date` value to drop the leading zeroes in your `datetime` object.

```py
DAG(..., start_date=datetime(2023,12,3,16,5), ...)
```